# Best practice for show thumbnails in Webpages

Tags: html, standards

If I want to show thumbnail view of an image and show the actual size image when the thumbnail is clicked ,
What is the best practice/standard way ? I mean,
1- Keep two files in local storage (say 800x600 and 120x160)and load them separately 
 
2- Keep only the full size image(say 800x600) and show the thumbnail by resizing it in HTML tags

```
width="160" height="120"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to use the two files, i.e.

```
1- Keep two files in local storage (say 800x600 and 120x160)and load them separately
```

As resizing is both computationally expensive and uses more bandwidth.

Ideally, each thumbnail image is compressed to about 10 - 30K (JPEG), and has an alt text. That way you can have about 20 or so in a table, easy to see. Like here: http://www.flickr.com/explore/interesting/7days/

And as you likely know, there are thumbnail creators, [like this one](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Editors/Simply-Thumbnail-Creator.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 - you save bandwidth and you also allow people with download limits to not use up their potential limit (such as on their phones). The only thing you end up giving up (assuming you automate the process) is hard drive space.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that the best is to keep two files. User can load a several big files, not everything. So, to load them all is unnecessary.

It may be very important for phones or such devices.

Answer (score 1):

best thing is keep high resolution version in the server and then based on the requirement dynamically re size the image. and if you want you can cache the file in the server side.if you are using C# this sample shows [how to resize dynamically](http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-dynamically-resize-images.html)

next option is keep separate files in server.